# Debugging seg fault caused by buffer over run

Tags: c, debugging, if-statement, segmentation-fault

I have the following code:

```
if (destIndex < destLen && srcIndex < srcLen)
    dest[destIndex++] = src[srcIndex++];
```

This code runs fine.

If I remove the  if, then the code crashes.

If I then run the following code

```
if (destIndex < destLen && srcIndex < srcLen)
    dest[destIndex++] = src[srcIndex++];
else
   fprintf(stderr, "Buffer Overrun\n");
```

Then I never get the print out "Buffer Overrun"

SO, how to debug this?

The seg fault only happens with optimizations turned on (no debug mode)

Comment: You have UB somewhere.  Good luck...

Comment: Show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The problem is somewhere in the code you didn't show.

Comment: @Jacko `destIndex` is becomming >= `destLen` and/or `srcIndex` is becomming >= `srcLen` somewhere, somehow... (assuming `destLen` and `srcLen` in fact correspond to the number of elements in `dest[]` and `src[]`)

Comment: @MartinJames Bingo!!!  destIndex is going negative.  Move your comment to an answer so I can give you full marks :)

Comment: I don't think I deserve full marks for that but, OK;)

Comment: Actually, that was a false alarm. Still broken

Comment: Dreck:( ...................................

Comment: @MartinJames if I use memcpy instead of pointer arithmetic, then the crash goes away. Would this still be explained by UB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have UB somewhere.  'Works in debug, but not release', or the other way round, is a massive undefined behaviour flag.

Check all your parameters with your debugger:)